# another sound as with subtitles

Tags: divx, movies

is it possible to get other sounds to a divx as it is with getting subtitles?
what is that format of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple audio streams in your video file. [Here](http://www.doom9.org/index.html?/dual-audio.htm)'s some more information (I'm guessing you're using AVI as your container format).